# Creating a delta table in S3 with Glue + delta lake creates a glue catalog table with wrong location

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, delta-lake

I am creating an ETL job with Glue using Delta lake framework. Example demo data is defined as:

```
data = {'visitor': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 
         'id': [1, 2, 3],
         'B': [1, 0, 1],
         'C': [1, 0, 0]}
```

And I am saving it to a delta table with the following lines of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(df)

dataFrame.write \
    .format("delta") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("path", "s3://example-bucket/deltalake_test/") \
    .saveAsTable("example-db.deltalake_test_delta")
```

After the job is finished, there is a table created in Glue Catalog, but the location is wrong as it contains:

```
__PLACEHOLDER__
```

string appended at the end of the supplied location. Is this issue with Glue+data lake or am I configuring something wrong? Due to the wrong location, table is not queryable in Athena either.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but no, I think I went ahead and created the tables manually as I was in a rush. Terribly hard to troubleshoot these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Check the location on database in Glue Catelog.
Make sure that it is not just s3://bucket-name. It should be s3://bucket-name/path